# SmartGWT, ZK and GenericFrame - Online Homework

Tags: bandwidth, javascript-framework, smartgwt, zk

Good day,

Our school, a small high school in semi-rural New Zealand, is currently looking into online homework solutions.  Being one of the IT guys, I have been asked to look into some of the options.  We have checked around and there are no robust solutions that cover what we are looking for.  So, we are considering development of our own system, either on our own or in collaboration with some other schools.

Before I put significant time into any one option, I would thought I should ask for some expert advice.

Please keep in mind that one of our major obstacles is that around 20% of our students are on dial-up because broadband is not available in their area.

We are also not limited to the technologies listed, they just are the ones that we have been looking into up to this point.

With that in mind, here goes.
1.  Is there a way to pre-determine the bandwidth needed for these technologies?
2.  If bandwidth continued to be too limiting, could the final solution stand alone so we could distribute it to students on CD or USB stick?
3.  What are some pros/cons of each for use with databases, specifically mysql or postgresql?  (After all we do need to keep track of lots of data)
4.  What are some pros/cons of each for of these RIA development?

I appreciate everyone for sharing their time and expertise on the matter.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

1) If you write full-AJAX application, such as in GWT, the bandwitch will be:
 a) the size of application java script, images, etc., you may consider that everything is loaded when user logs in (cache for images may seems to be big, but it's easily overloaded)
 b) the size of communication - in GWT it depends only from you! no magic full-frame reloading, sending is only what YOU are wanting to send

2) I do not catch your point, stand alone applications can be distributed such way, applications that use databases generally can't

3) postgresql has high compatibility with Oracle - same transaction+select for update behaviour, pgPLSQL is highly inspired by PL/SQL (easy to rewrite stored procedures).

Answer (score 1):

I personally suggest MySQL for a school project for its simplicity. PostgreSQL is powerful but a bit complicate to configure and the visual tool for optimizing queries not good.

Without considering the bandwidth, I definitely suggest ZK since, again, it is much easier to learn, to develop and to maintain (also much more powerful). The bandwidth consumption and latency of GWT really depends how much effort you want to invest, and how skillful your people are familiar with distributed computing, while the network bandwidth is basically the states of UI (not data), which is reasonably small. In short, you could have the best network bandwidth and latency if you optimize it at the best with GWT, while ZK is less to worry but, if you want to improve, you have to use jQuery (i.e, in JavaScript).

Comment: Just found you mentioned SmartGWT in title. Please notice that SmartGWT is very different from GWT. It has its own data source mechanism to improve the productivity but it means you have no much control of the bandwidth. Also, it is a GWT layer on top of a JavaScript solution, SmartClient -- it means it is hard to debug in GWT's tool

Answer (score 1):

Thanks lechlukasz, I appreciate your comments and insight.

I will clarify my point about stand alone applications.  We have a number of students, as high as 20%, who do not have access to broadband due to their geographic location.  We are considering, as part of the design, how we may be able to distribute a stand alone version.

For instance, if we were to abstract all the database calls using a separate class in GWT, we could recompile a stand alone version that didn't make the database calls.  The database would likely only be for tracking results and reporting.

In reality, we would likely implement the front end product first with references to empty methods for storing the results in a database and implement those methods at a later time.

For the record, we have started to code up some test cases using GWT/SmartGWT and are pleased with the results.  Although we cannot comment on the other technologies considered because we didn't try them to the same extent, we are pleased with the results to this point of the project.

Cheers,
Ben